# Resize Imageview in SeekBar onProgressChanged

Tags: android, imageview, seekbar

Im trying to resize a ImageView based on the SeekBar progress

Here is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_pizzaSize_icon"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="Pizza"
        android:src="@drawable/pizza" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar_pizzaSize"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:progress="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_pizzaSize_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        tools:text="PIZZA SIZE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside my fragment, I tried this approach based on [this answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stretch-an-image-using-Seekbar-in-Android)

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    int diff = i - previousProcess;
    scaleImage(mImageView, diff);
    previousProcess = i;
}

public void scaleImage(ImageView img, int scale) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    float width = bitmap.getWidth();
    float height = bitmap.getHeight();
    width += scale * widthScaleRatio;
    height += scale * heightScaleRatio;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) width, (int) height,
            true);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

But my ImageView don't resize, it keeps the same original size only moving a little when I change the SeekBar.

My idea is to open the fragment with the ImageView only occupying 50% of the width, and the SeekBar to be in the position 0. The amount of positions available to pick up will vary. When the SeekBar reach the last index, the ImageView will occupy about 95% of the width, leaving space for margins.
I know this idea have more complex operations than my question about resizing the ImageView, but giving a big picture about what I want to achieve maybe help you to lead me to the right way.
This will be part of a activity where the user will mount a pizza, first chosen the size of the pizza, and bigger the size, bigger the ImageView.

Comment: Check the `diff ` value on scaleImage

Comment: @BrianHoang placing a log after initialyzing diff and before creating the scaled bitmap give me this output:

diff is 0  
Width = 1080.000000, Height = 1080.000000  
diff is 1  
Width = 1280.000000, Height = 1280.000000  
diff is 1  
Width = 1480.000000, Height = 1480.000000  
diff is 1  
Width = 1680.000000, Height = 1680.000000  
diff is 1  
Width = 1880.000000, Height = 1880.000000

Comment: Because `diff = 1` -> your image not scale. try `diff = i `

Answer (score 0):

Give the **ImageView height & width** **wrap_content**  and try it

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_pizzaSize_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/Pizza" />
```

Comment: Same result, ImageView dont chage